# Custom pages or Custom Posts

Tags: custom-field, api

I am looking for a way to create custom pages, regarding the information that it holds on the WP CMS, I don't care about the layout, that will be handled separately. (To be clear, I want a custom page in the editor for custom CMS input, not in point of the view of the site visitor)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am using (well... trying to, actually) GraphQL

I was able to add a field to the response following the documentation, as follows

```
add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {
    register_graphql_field( 'Page', 'color', [
       'type' => 'String',
       'description' => __( 'The color of the post', 'wp-graphql' ),
       'resolve' => function( $post ) {
         $color = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'color', true );
         return ! empty( $color ) ? $color : 'blue';
       }
    ] );
  } );
```

But there are two problems here: First, how do I get the field to be filled within the page? Do I create a form for the admin of the site to input the color?

Second: This added the `color` field to all pages, and each page will be different. I want custom fields per page, not added to all pages

Thank you very much, I am very much lost

Edit: This is what I did, please let me know if it is wrong

removed the `add_action` from the PHP file

installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ and https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-acf

created a custom fields form for each page (actually one until now)

activate `Show in graphql`

And then I can get the fields in GraphQL Api

Comment: About ACF, under ACF > Add New then "Location", you can set to display the fields for specific pages you have, if you want to display the fields for a "custom page type" (not a post type), you can create a page template and set the ACF to show the fields only when editing the pages using the page template.

Comment: Thank you @Diana, I will do that